# How does a server identify php script instance from another server who runs multiple instances?

Tags: php, http, proxy, parallel-processing, multiple-instances

I have 2 servers. The main server acts as a web service for the server2 and server2 is talking to the clients.

[image: servers]

Server2 runs a php script that gets some data from the client, then sends it to the main server and then reads the content of a certain page on the Main Server (which was generated according to the data of the client) and also reads the http headers that comes back from the main server in order to get a cookie value.

Server 2 Code:

```
some code ...

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'value1',
        'var2' => $_POST["var2"],
        'var3' => $_POST["var3"]
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_get_contents("http://www.mainserver.com", false, $context);
$cookieContent = getCookieContent($http_response_header);
SetCookie('myCookie', $cookieContent, $loginTime, '/', $url, false);

more code ....
```

The main server doesn't run a php script but it writes the cookie value as expected.
The cookie value is unique and being generated according to the client's details that were passed by server2.

So, basically, server2 acts as "proxy" (or reverse proxy) and should set the unique cookie value he gets from the main server for each client.

My question is:

Does my logic works? I know it works for 1 client, but what happens when multiple clients access the same script on server2? How the main server knows to return the answer with the correct unique value to the correct php instance on server2?

In other words, is there any chance that a client will send a request to server2 and server2 will return an answer with a unique value that belongs to a different client?

Comment: It looks like your server2 is acting as a [reverse-proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). I wonder why you would want to build one from scratch. Have you looked at existing solutions like [Apache traffic server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_Server)?

Comment: Because server2 does other things too and also uses a database of it's own, not just passing information between the client and the main server.

Comment: Well so are most if not all reverse-proxies :) I was thinking maybe you could use an existing software as a base and see if you can implement your specific functions on top of it.

Comment: Well, I don't need more than what I already have, I just need to understand how things work to make sure my code will do what I want it to do.

Comment: Your logic is ok but not ideal under any situations that I can think of. Is "main server" accepting connections from any form of regular HTTP client or do all requests come from ""server2" and similar hosts? Can you be more specific about the tasks being performed on "server2" and "main server"?

Comment: setcookie wont work with streams, and anything you do regarding stream context for file_get_contents  will only last for the single instance of the call. in other words, it will open a connection based on the provided context, request a page (or read a stream until EOF), and then close the connection all in one function. the connection is lost after each call. you'll want to use sockets, regular streams or cURL if the connection is to be sustained through the entire session that the original client is connected to "server2"

Comment: @ClosetGeek I don't need to sustain the connection, moreover, it should be as short as possible, I only need server2 to "ask a question" and "get an answer" from the main server. Note: the main server cannot be access from anywhere else but server2. I also don't understand why you say setcookie won't work - it worksm that's a fact. Did you read the answers?

Comment: I was referring to setcookie with php streams specifically, but I still stand corrected. I've been coding PHP for over ten years and have never had to use $http_response_header to get a cookie. This isn't a typical pattern for PHP and I would usually use cURL in this type of situation.

Comment: You should probably be passing ```X-Forwarded-For``` header to ```Main Server``` from ```Server2```. ```Main Server``` might not make any use of it, but it is the correct way to inform the server that you are passing it requests on behalf of the client. This sometimes resolves per IP request limits if too many requests are seen as coming from ```Server2```. Although I don't see why it would return a value for a different client though, unless there is a bug in the way ```Main Server``` handles requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does work, because PHP on Server 2 processes the script independently for each request from a client. In turn, each of the execution instances of the PHP script receive their own HTTP request from `stream_context_create()`, most probably even in different TCP connections. There is no way the values for `$context` get accidentally swapped between execution instances and a client receives a response originally intended for another client.

Your problem doesn't even require the existence of a »Main server«. When you're writing a PHP script, critical information about how the requests are handled by it, is hidden from you, which is why you might be confused. But this is a good thing:

1. If you abstract away the details about how PHP is invoked, your webserver has many (configurable) choices on how to handle requests from concurrent clients: It could e.g. use multiple threads, multiple processes, serialize all the executions, use a threadpool. You wouldn't want to rewrite your PHP code, just because your Webserver has to use threads instead of processes. If you write your PHP code well, you can use the same PHP code in different contexts, e.g. call it from the command line.
2. You are getting certain basic guarantees, like that no client will accidentally get a response intended for some other client.

However, if you want your »Main server« to know, that it is serving different clients, you have to inform it accordingly. This could work with passing on cookies (in your case, you pass on cookies from the »Main server« to the client, but passing on cookies from the clients to the »Main server« is missing).

Comment: I don't need the main server to know he serves different clients, he only generates a page and a cookie value according to the post data he gets, that's good enough for me. If I understand your answer correctly, I don't need to change my code or send extra data to the main server in order to make it work for multiple clients.

By the way, these 2 servers and their functionality is a given fact for me, I don't have a choice, so I can't give up the main server.

Comment: I didn't want to say that you should remove the »main server«, I just wanted to simplify the problem by leaving it out of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to implement your own reverse-proxy system then.

Basically your proxy (server2 in your example) will need to memorize all what is needed to

- pass a client request to the server,
- answer the client once the server has generated the wanted page
- handle the case where the server does not answer (i.e. request timeouts)

In a simple client-server exchange, the server will use the HTTP headers sent by the client to produce an immediate reply, so these headers do not need to be memorized.

In a proxy architecture, the proxy will not reply immediately (it will ask the server for the actual reply instead).

During the time needed for the server to produce the reply, the proxy has to memorize the reference of the original client's request, to

- use it to recreate the final reply once the server finally produces it,
- handle request cancellation from the client side

It means the proxy will have to handle two two-ways communication channels asynchronously, while a simple server can handle the requests synchronously.

What your example shows is the uplink from the proxy to the server.

In this uplink, the proxy must provide transparently all the informations passed by the client and add some indication of how the server shall pass back the completed request to him.

The `$context` variable of your example should contain the HTTP headers as passed by the client, plus some backlink to the proxy, that the server will use to direct its response to the proxy instead of the client.

In turn, the server will process the request just as if it had been sent directly by the client. However, once the request is processed, it will use the backlink to answer the proxy.

The proxy will get a response from the server, and use the memorized request context to decide what to do with the result. The client might have dropped the request in the mean time, in which case the result will simply be ignored. Otherwise, it will use the request context to pass the response to the client.

All this being said, the unique ID delivered by the server is not necessary, since the server will never talk to the client directly. What matters is that the proxy and the server can identify clearly which request they are working on.

In short, the only thing required is a request identifier between the server and the proxy.

You can still generate a unique ID for each client based on cookies or IP address or any other means, but that will not be different from, say, session handling in a proxy-less client-server architecture.

Comment: That's a nice answer, but I already did the implementation part. My question is about my code/algorithm. I'm trying to understand how the file_get_contents works. If it opens an unique connection between the main server and server2 so when server2 will run the script again a different connection will be opened. In this case I don't need to memorize anything. The connections are unique and the servers can communicate on a different connections simultaneously.

Comment: file_get_contents simply reads from a stream until it reaches the end of input. The interesting part is the 3rd "context" parameter that allows to prepend anything you want to the result. This context can be set to gather HTTP headers from the request. See [HTTP context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) for further details. It is a bit like reading the full response of the server in one function call. Context can also be used to tweak the response to a request.

Comment: you control this whole chain?  I'd either go with this solution or since your server2 is currently NOT a reverse proxy and is in fact running php then have it be THE webserver and do the cookie management. then the main server is basically an authoritative source of information and you are effectively using it like a webservice for server2 to get data from it.   At some point you could swap out mainserver for anything else then even consolidating it all on server2.